# Join and filter JSON files using jq

Tags: json, jq

i am working on a Yelp json corpus with `jq`, desperately trying to accomplish some join & filter task.
The *business.json* contains **categories** and **business_id**, from which I can get all ids of restaurants, using which I want to filter the *review.json* to extract all reviews for restaurants.

Sounds straight forward in RDBMS but I want to learn the `jq` way.

Can anyone help?

Things I have tried.

1. Extracted business ID and saved in id.txt. But it is impossible to refer to id.txt in `jq`.
2. In a script loop all ids and execute `jq --arg id $line '. | select( .business_id | contains($id))' reviews.json`
3. Joining the two json files maybe possible but I am reluctant to do, due to the size of the files (~1G)

Edited according to comments:

Simplified sample input:
business.json

> {
>
> "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA",
>
> "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018",  >   >
>
> "categories": ["Restaurant"]
>
> }

reviews.json

> {
>
> "date": "2012-05-15",
>
> "text": "Got a letter in the mail last week that said Dr. Goldberg is moving to Arizona to take a new position there in June.  He will be missed very much.  \n\nI think finding a new doctor in NYC that you actually like might almost be as awful as trying to find a date!",
>
> "type": "review",
>
> "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA"
>       }

Best attemp:
Able to march documents with multiple ids, like

`jq '. | select( .business_id | contains("LRKJF43s9-3jG9Lgx4zODg", "uGykseHzyS5xAMWoN6YUqA"))' reviews.json`

But couldn't replace the query strings with variables,

`jq --arg t vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA '. | select( .business_id | contains(env.t))' reviews.json` doesn't work

Comment: Please add a meaningful sample of the input data (i.e. JSON) and your most promising attempt in jq.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i edited in the original post.

Comment: Regarding your last snippet, using `$t` instead of `env.t` should work.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. However, it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: I also tried using while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do;
    jq --arg id $line '. | select( .business_id | contains($id))' review.json
done < "$1" to loop through the external file but it doesn't run in the loop

Comment: It's unclear what the contents of your json files are. Is it just a single instance of an object that looks like that? An array of those objects? A stream of those objects (one object after the other)? Depending on what it is, the approach will vary.

Comment: Hi Jeff, sorry for the confusion but yes, the actual dataset looks like a collection of those. I don't know how to edit JSON format prettily here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your description whether each business and each review is a top-level object. However it appears that you can arrange that both businesses and reviews can be presented as streams, so in the following, I will assume that:

```
(a) both reviews.json and businesses.json are files of JSON objects;
(b) it is acceptable to read all the reviews into memory.
```

(If, conversely, it is only acceptable to read the businesses into memory, the following can easily be revised.)

The logic is: read all the reviews, and then for each restaurant, extract the reviews for that restaurant.

```
select(.categories | index("Restaurant"))
| .business_id as $business_id
| $reviews[]
| select( .type == "review" and .business_id == $business_id)
```

Invocation:

```
$ jq --slurpfile reviews reviews.json yelp.jq businesses.json
```

Please note that the --slurpfile option is NOT available in jq 1.4.

(If reviews.json is already an array of JSON objects, then you could use --argfile reviews reviews.json, and thus would not need jq 1.5.)